# Seg fault after calling destructor successfully or calling empy destructor. C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, destructor

I am very sorry that I am not able to provide more details of my code, since I am taking over another project. The class structures are very complicated and I am unable to reproduce the issue using an easy example.

Essentally if I delete an object, all the statements in the destructor was executed successfully, but as soon as the destructor finishes execution, seg fault happens. Even if I just make the destructor empty and not do anything, the seg fault still happens. This class does not have any base class.

My code looks like this:

```
ParallelSynthesizer* p = new ParallelSynthesizer(argc, argv);
p->synthesize();
delete p;
cout << "after deleting" << endl;
```

"after deleting" was not shown, as the seg fault happens before that. But the destructor of p is executed successfully.

[EDITED AFTER SOME COMMENTS] the "synthesize()" method does use multithreading, but it is very straightforward:

```
pthread_t threads[num_threads];
// makes the "params" array here. skipped. 
for (int i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, synthesizeThreadMethod, (void*)(params[i]));
}

for (int i=0; i<num_threads; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);;
}
```

This pretty much all in the synthesize() method, so I don't think multithreading will result in any issue.

I am using g++ on linux. Does anybody know the possible causes of this problem?

I apologize again for not being able to find an easy example that produces this error.

Comment: Does it have any base classes?

Comment: So what runs after the destructor?

Comment: @GMan: nothing. I just put an output statement after "delete p;" The seg fault happens before the output statement executes. But destructor was executed successfully, verified by output statements in the destructor.

Comment: you haven't overload std::new by any chance, have you?

Comment: @littleadv: no I didnt. HOw dare I. :)

Comment: Could you provide us with the implementation of the class?

Comment: I notice you apparently have concurrent code. Are you sure `p` isn't being used after you delete it? If `synthesize` does something in another thread, that thread might be trying to read `p`. What does it do?

Comment: `p->synthesize()` doesn't start threads which continue after the call returns and have access to the object, does it?  The Parallel part makes me wonder...

Comment: @GMan, @Tom: thank you so much for your comments. I updated my post, I dont think the threading part would cause that issue.

Comment: @usfish: Comment out the definition of `synthesize`, then run your code. If the problem goes away, the issue is multi-threading. Locate where in the threads `p` is used, and decide what you want to do.

Comment: @GMan, Thank you so much for your time. I tried what you suggested but the error is still there. =(

Comment: What is the definition of the constructor of `ParallelSynthesizer`?

Comment: @GMan, it is just like this: ParallelSynthesizer(int argc, char* argv[]);...... not sure if it helps..

Comment: @usfish: That's the *declaration*, not the *definition*. The implementation of the constructor is its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause is that another object tries to access `p` after it got deleted.

**Update** You could try and run your code through valgrind. Depends a little on how well you can isolate the problem before hand. My guess so far would be that you do something bad inside your class (like constructing an object and passing `p` as parameter to it).

Comment: chris, thanks for your comment, I added a bit more details in my original post to clear some thing up.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say based on what you've said, but it sounds like you've got some heap corruption.

This kind of problem is tricky to trace and it's virtually impossible for Stack Overflow readers to fix this for you given a large code base.  I would recommend running a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), which will track memory accesses and give you a hint at where things went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the crash happens during `operator delete(void*)`, which is invoked by `delete p;` right after the destructor.

There are lots of possible causes for messing up the heap in a way that could cause a crash.  A common one would be that some code previously wrote to memory before or after a `new`-ed object.  I would run the program under `valgrind memcheck`; it's a very useful tool specifically for tracing down this sort of error.